# How to force in-memory chunked sort in Spark SQL?

Tags: apache-spark

Parquet file format is sensitive to the order of records. Its columnar encoding may produce significant smaller files depending on sort order.
On the other hand, sorting a terabyte of input records is highly expensive.

Splitting into chunks of let's say 10GB allows in-memory sort while generating nearly as small parquet files as if the entire 1 TB was fully sorted.

Is it possible to instruct Spark SQL to do chunked sort prior to generating parquet file?

Another use case would be merging many small Parquet files into one while using chunked sort before writing the unified Parquet file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I am aware there is no such option available out-of-the box in **Spark < 2.0.0**. One thing you can try is to combine `coalesce` with Hive `SORT BY` clause before writing which should have **a similar** effect:

```scala
val df: DataFrame = ???
val n: Int = ??? //

df.coalesce(n)
df.coalesce(n).registerTempTable("df")
sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM df SORT BY foo, bar").write.parquet(...)
```

or

```
df.coalesce(n).sortWithinPartitions($"foo", $"bar").write.parquet(...)
```

Keep in mind that `SORT BY` is not equivalent to `DataFrame.sort`.

**Spark 2.0.0** introduced `sortBy` and `bucketBy` methods where the latter one *sorts the output in each bucket by the given columns* and [should support Parquet](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/e23370ec617c527ffa3a1f7d285ee2c4ffc51b77/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameWriter.scala#L258):

```scala
val df: DataFrame = ???
val nBuckets: Int = ???

df.write.bucketBy(nBuckets, "foo").sortBy("foo", "bar").saveAsTable(...)
```

**Note**: This seems to work just when saving Parquet files with `saveAsTable` but it doesn't look like it supports parquet writer directly (`df.write.bucketBy(...).sortBy(...).parquet(...)`) in `spark-2.0.0-preview`.

Comment: Thanks zero323, As far as I understood, sortWithinPartitions just avoids the final merge sort. However, each partition will fully sort its data and if not fit into memory, files will be used.
Where can I get more info on bucketBy and version 2.0.0 in general?

Comment: `sortWithinPartitions` avoids both final merge as well as shuffle required to perform full sort. As far as I am aware Spark typically doesn't use in-memory sort because it doesn't assume that data for a single partition fits in a memory. I am not sure though if there are any SQL specific optimizations in play. You could convert Iterator to local structure and sort directly both using `rdd.mapPartitions`. Regarding `sortBy` the only reference I know is [corresponding JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-12539) and source / tests.

Comment: `spark-2.2.0` doesn't support `df.write.bucketBy(...).sortBy(...).parquet(...)` but raise proper exception. [SPARK-15718 SQL better error message for writing bucketed data](https://github.com/apache/spark/commit/f34aadc54ca1a9fd4236a928d342324b26fb3a12)